# Character Statistics after Uninstall

Tags: payday-2

PayDay 2 maintains a save file on your local machine which contains some character stats, I don't know the specifics of everything it contains, but I do know I had to restore a backup of it once as the game couldn't load my character skills - which resulted in me dropping XP / cash.

Anyway, my question is, if you uninstall PayDay 2 and this file gets deleted, is it backed up on any Overkill servers?  Or is it once you uninstall you reset your progress?   There is the Steam Cloud, but if you didn't enable this option what would happen?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that without steam cloud you will just lose all of your progress.

Comment: Overkill have no record of your save, it's entirely local. However Payday 2 does work with Steam's cloud saves feature (Though I wouldn't rely on it, a local save is a safer option)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I nearly lost all my PD2 progress on a previous occasion, when the game crashed and I loaded it up again before cloud sync had finished, most likely causing a sync conflict and resulting in a corrupt or missing file.

On this occasion, I was lucky enough to find that Steam automatically corrected this issue and downloaded my progress again after I quit and let it resync.

However, before quitting the game, I checked out this [PAYDAY 2 Savegame Backup and Restore Guide](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=170416480) to make sure I covered all bases. It documents where your saves are, and what to do if you encounter an error that could potentially lead to your progress getting reset.

Answer (score 0):

You'll either need to save the file manually or sync it via Steam Cloud.
Make sure that payday 2 is syncronized with Steam cloud before you start uninstalling.